# multiple Django projects apache virtual hosts

Tags: django, apache, mod-wsgi

I'm a newbie to apache.
So I'm trying to run at least two different django projects on one Ubuntu Server with a single IP address.

- IP: 123.456.789
- Domain 1: www.example.de for Project1
- Domain 2:
  www.test.de for Proejct2

The DNS for both domains is pointing on the same IP Address.
I'm using apache2 with mod_wsgi in Daemon mode.
Each Project has its own directory in ~/.
I've also installed a virtaulenv with python inside the Project directorys

The problem is that no matter how I configurate the apache2.conf, both domains point to Project1.
What is weird is that they even do when it when I comment all the custom settings in apache2.conf.
Can someone please explain this?

here is my apache2.conf

```
Listen 80
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.example.de
    WSGIScriptAlias / /home/user/example/example-project/wsgi.py
    Alias /static/ /home/user/example/static/
    WSGIPythonPath /home/user/example
    <Directory /home/user/example/static>
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
    <Directory /home/user/example/example>
        <Files wsgi.py>
            Require all granted
        </Files>
    </Directory>
    WSGIDaemonProcess example.de python-path=/home/user/example:/home/user/example/exampleenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages
    WSGIProcessGroup example.de
</VirtualHost>

Listen 8080
<VirtualHost *:80>
    Servername www.test.de
    WSGIScriptAlias / /home/user/test/test-project/wsgi.py
    Alias /static/ /home/user/test/static/
    <Directory /home/user/test/static>
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
    <Directory /home/user/test/test-project>
        <Files wsgi.py>
            Require all granted
        </Files>
    </Directory>
    WSGIDaemonProcess test.de python-path=/home/user/test:/home/user/test/testenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages
    WSGIProcessGroup test.de
</VirtualHost>
```

Even if there is something wrong with my config, why does it still run when i comment everything in this blog? Where else is apache getting the information from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The topic of why your requests may end up being handled by the wrong Django instance has been documented in detail in the blog post at:

- http://blog.dscpl.com.au/2012/10/requests-running-in-wrong-django.html

There are multiple possible situations described in that blog post as to what can go wrong.

In your case it sounds like the virtual host for the second, if in a separate file, may not have been enabled and so the web server is not even reading the file. The consequence is that Apache will send all requests to the first VirtualHost if it can't find an appropriate match using name based virtual hosting.

I would suggest adding a syntax error to the second virtual host ('xxx' on a line by itself) and see if Apache outputs an error when trying to start. This will confirm whether file being read.

Comment: Yes I'm getting a syntax error, in the second virtual host. It's really weird, even when I comment all the lines from the first virtual host, all domains are directing me to the first VH.

Comment: Add at global scope outside of all ``VirtualHost`` definitions, ``WSGIRestrictEmbedded On``. This will ensure mod_wsgi only runs in daemon processes and nothing can run in embedded mode. May not change anything, but want to check that isn't somehow finding some definition that has it running in embedded mode. If it fails after adding that may be useful to know. BTW, are they your actual hostnames, or have you changed the configuration to protect the real ones?

Comment: Ok, I now realize that it all works just fine.
Both projects were basicly the same, I just changed a <h1>-tag in Project2 and thought I would see the difference. Well I did not, I guess because the site is cached somewhere on serversite. Now I just have to figure out where...

Comment: Read http://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/reloading-source-code.html Changing code of disk doesn't mean things will automatically be reflected in what is being served. In your case though it sounds a bit more life life times on cached pages.

Answer (score 1):

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

ServerName www.example1.com
ServerAlias example1.com
ServerAdmin admin@example1.com

DocumentRoot "/var/www/example1"

WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/example1/example1/wsgi.py
WSGIDaemonProcess www.example1.com python-path=/var/www/example1:/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages

<Location />
WSGIProcessGroup www.example1.com
</Location>

<Directory /var/www/example1>
<Files wsgi.py>
    Require all granted
</Files>
</Directory>

ErrorLog /var/www/logs/example1.log

</VirtualHost>


<VirtualHost *:80>

ServerName www.example2.com
ServerAlias exolcorporation.com
ServerAdmin admin@example2.com

DocumentRoot "/var/www/example2"

WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/example2/example2/wsgi.py
WSGIDaemonProcess www.example2.com python-path=/var/www/example2:/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages

<Location />
WSGIProcessGroup www.example2.com
</Location>

<Directory /var/www/example2>
<Files wsgi.py>
    Require all granted
</Files>
</Directory>

ErrorLog /var/www/logs/example2.log

</VirtualHost>
```

try this replacing paths and domain names
in WSGIDaemonProcess use path of your virtualenv 
i didn't used virtualenv in this example
this code works fine for me on aws ubuntu

Comment: will check out tomorrow, any idea on why apache runs my project even though I've deleted all related lines in the apache.conf?